# Importing Excel sheet using OpenyPyxl leads to error '__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'extend''

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm trying to use Python/openpyxl to import a fairly hefty xl spreadsheet, unfortunately I think that the sheet has some fonts/styles that are not recognized. There are various work constraints that are preventing me from updating this package - which I believe would resolve the issue immediately - (I'm currently using V 2.03).

Other than updating the package, is there any other way to import this?

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Testing Report - Copy.xlsx')
type(wb)
names = wb.get_sheet_names()
```

**Resulting error**

..........
 File "C:\Hoops\Deployer\Other\PythonDevTools\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\style.py", line 106, in parse_font
    return Font(**font)
TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'extend'

Thanks!

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/336/unexpected-keyword-argument-extend

Comment: Alas this file is also locked down so I can't manually add this. Thanks anyway Tim.

Comment: You must update your version of openpyxl. The version you're using is no longer supported.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice Charlie